# How do you adjust the height of mat-table header and rows?

Tags: angular, mat-table

I'm building an Angular 7 site and I have a couple of mat-tables. They look like this:

[image]

The template:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="projects">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="projectName">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{ project.name }}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="endDate">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>End Date</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{ project.endDate }}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="overdueTodos">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Overdue Todos</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{ project.overdueTodos }}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let project; columns: displayedColumns;" style="background-color: green; padding: 0; margin: 0; max-height: 10px;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

The stylesheet:

```
mat-cell {
    font-size: 8pt;
    max-height: 10px;
}
```

I'm wondering how to adjust the height of the rows.

As you can tell, the inline styling on the mat-row (max-height: 10px) doesn't work. Neither does it work in the mat-cell styling. I also tried just height: 10px. I also tried at the level of the mat-table.

How does one style the height of rows and headers in a mat-table (or other styling for that matter).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from the Angular Material documentation examples, mat-cells have some padding, try to remove it or adjust it to your needs.
Also, there're normal `<tr></tr>`, `<th></th>` and `<td></td>` with attributes instead of `<mat-cell></mat-cell>` etc.

Check out this page
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: Thanks igor, I also found this stackblitz which seems to work: thttps://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjjdpjqvvde?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-footer-example.html. It uses classic table elements as well, and the styling is done in the css file very specifically targeting tr.mat-footer-row and such. I tested by targeting tr.mat-row { height: 10px; } and it works.

Answer (score 2):

To adjust rows height use the following style:

```
tr.mat-row { height: 20px; }
```